# To be able to log into Facebook while using MediaWiki

Tags: facebook, unix, authentication, mediawiki

I'm struggling to understand what I need to do for a piece of work that I have assigned. The question is as follows, plus I have MediaWiki already installed on my Unix machine.

As standard MediaWiki requires each user to create an account. Use an extension to allow 
users to “log in with facebook”. They will then be able to link their account already created on the private wiki with their facebook account.

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow is for questions on actual programming implementation, not installing other software.

There is a MediaWiki extension that allows for Facebook integration:

[http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Facebook](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aFacebook)

You will need to install the extension by following the directions.